Pythonanywhere ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded even though I have enough space
I am trying to install a site package for my Django website on pythonanywhere.com and after downloading the site package (pyspark), it says :
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded
Which it should say because I have enough space available.

I have no idea why it would say that after completing the download. I clearly have enough space for it to download and yet it keeps saying that. What can I try next?

Some packages require more disk space during the compiliation time than they take after (or before) the installation.  So you could get the disk space error and see less then 100% disk quota afterwards.

It is possible that the package you're trying to install needs more space than is available in your account.
Looking at the help page for this issue on PythonAnywhere, it says:

Your account on PythonAnywhere has a specific amount of storage space available for saving files -- Python scripts, images, data, or anything else you want. Free accounts get a disk quota of 512MiB; paid accounts get more, the exact amount depending on what kind of account you have.

You can run du -hs /tmp ~/.[!.]* ~/* | sort -h in a bash console to find out how much space is being used in various places in your file storage and du -s -B 1 /tmp ~/.[!.]* ~/* | awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}' to see how many bytes are used (you may have to convert to mb for better understanding 1 byte = 0.000001 mb).
In my case, uninstalling packages I no longer needed helped save disk space. You can run pip uninstall <packagename>. Also, you can clean up any old, unused virtualenvs with rmvirtualenv my-old-venv-name. Finally delete your cache files with rm -rf ~/.cache/*.
See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DiskQuota/
